# add a row above the selected row in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a row above the selected row to the table in jquery. How to achieve this using jquery. Suppose the table has 4 rows, if i am selecting the 3rd row and click on the add row button a new row should be added above the top of the 3rd row.

Comment: can you add some html and js please.

Comment: Use `insertBefore`? http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have not misunderstood your question, I have worked on a solution for this. I hope this helps. Plus, always provide the code snippet in your question as that helps to get to the root of the problem.

Here is the dummy HTML for that:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button>
      Click1
    </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button>
      Click2
    </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button>
      Click3
    </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button>
      Click4
    </button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the basic jQuery for that purpose, as suggested earlier, I have used `insertBefore()` jQuery function:

```
$('table tr td button').click(function(){
    var appendThis =$("<tr><td>Added</td></tr>"); 
    appendThis.insertBefore($(this).closest("tr"));
});
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks.